# C# create a pdf from html that uses react

Tags: c#, reactjs, wkhtmltopdf, dinktopdf

I'm looking for a way to have server side rendered pdf from a html+css+javascript source. The idea here is to have a preview and report designer available on the client side using react components.

I've tried DinkToPdf that can render PDF from html pages, however it seems like only the top level component was mounted in the page when the PDF was rendered, even when enabling javascript in the renderer.

Client side pdf rendering using canvases is not an option since data can be easily tampered with.

Comment: You are going to have a REALLY hard time with this.  In order for any software to convert HTML to a PDF, it basically has to know how to parse and render HTML... e.g. almost like a mini-browser.  The best such component I have ever used to render PDFs from HTML is Aspose.PDF.  It is NOT free and I seriously doubt it can handle this.  Chances of a free PDF generator doing it are slim to none.

Answer (score 1):

I did this recently using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which is a command line version of webkit (which I think Chrome is based on).  I was able to load/parse and generate a graph using css/d3/rickshaw.

The basic process is:

- Create the HTML using [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight)
- shell out to wkhtmltopdf with the generated html.
- do something with generated pdf.